# How to print out a label for each value in console.log()

Tags: javascript, console.log

I'm having trouble figuring out how to customize console.log() so that it automatically prints out the label for each argument I pass into it. For example, I often do something like this, so that it's clear what each log is printing out:

`console.log('firstName: ', firstName);`

I would love to be able to simplify this to:

`my.log(firstName);`

Is there any way to pass the variable names of the caller args into `console.log()`? Or is there another way to do this? My wish is that I don't have to type out the variable name twice, just the once. And ideally print out multiple arguments each with its own label on its own line in the console. I'm aware that I can access the arguments list, but I don't know how to un-eval() each argument to get just its variable name, if that makes sense. I'm hoping it's something super-easy I missed.

Comment: I added answer, hope it will work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Doing it the way you want is impossible (the log function doesn't know what name you called things.)
The way I work around this is to use the object shorthand `{firstName}`to create a temporary object.

You can then either use `.log` or `.table` to display it:

```js
const firstName = 'bob';
console.log({firstName});
console.table({firstName});
// It also works for multiple variables:
const lastName = 'smith';
console.log({firstName, lastName});
```

Comment: Ooh very nice !

Answer (score 4):

You could use [console.table()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/table) to print things in a more readable form:

(Look in the real console to see it.)

```js
var obj = {
  firstName: "name",
  lastName: "smith"
};

function log(obj) {
  console.table(obj);
}
log(obj);
```

Comment: I've never used console.table(). I'll check it out, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```js
var my = { 
    log : function(name) { 
              console.log('firstName: ', name); 
          } 
    };

my.log("Rohit");
```

Comment: But 'firstName' ought not be hardcoded -- it's dynamic depending on the name of the variable passed in from the caller.

Comment: @Ringo Why downvoted ? It's just an example you can pass `firstname` dynamically in the `my.log`

Comment: I didn't downvote it, it was someone else. I actually never downvote anyone who tries to help me!

Comment: I think David might be correct, that what I was asking to do is impossible.